# Reading texels after imageStore()

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm modifying texels of a texture with imageStore() and after that i'm reading those texels in some other shader as sampler2D with texture() but i get the values which were stored in the texture before the imageStore(). With imageLoad() it works fine but i need to use filtering and the performance of texture() is better, so is there a way to get the modified data with texture()?

**Edit:**

First fragment shader(for writing):

```
#version 450 core

layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D img;

in vec2 vs_uv_out;

void main()
{
    imageStore(img, ivec2(vs_uv_out), vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

Second fragment shader(for reading):

```
#version 450 core

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 vs_uv_out;

out vec4 out_color;

void main()
{
    out_color = texture(tex, vs_uv_out);
}
```

Thats how i run the shaders:

```
glUseProgram(shader_programs[0]);
glBindImageTexture(0, texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, 
                   GL_RGBA32F);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glUseProgram(shader_programs[1]);
glBindTextureUnit(0, texture);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

i made this simple application to test that because the real one is very complex, i first clear the texture with red but the texels won't appear blue(except of using imageLoad in the second frag. shader).

Comment: You need to describe the situation more precisely. Where are you doing the writing and where are you doing the reading? Post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, that's easy then. [Image Load/Store's](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) writes uses an [incoherent memory model](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access), not the synchronous model most of the rest of OpenGL uses. As such, just because you write something with Image Load/Store doesn't mean it's visible to anyone else. You have to explicitly make it visible for reading.

You need a [`glMemoryBarrier` call](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMemoryBarrier.xhtml) between the rendering operation that writes the data and the operation that reads it. And since the reading operation is a texture fetch, the correct barrier to use is `GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT`.

And FYI: your `imageLoad` was able to read the written data only due to *pure luck*. Nothing guaranteed that it would be able to read the written data. To ensure such reads, you'd need a memory barrier as well. Though obviously a different one: `GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT`.

---

Also, `texture` takes normalized texture coordinates. `imageStore` takes integer pixel coordinates. Unless that texture is a rectangle texture (and it's not, since you used `sampler2D`), it is impossible to pass the exact same coordinate to both `imageStore` and `texture`.

Therefore, either your pixels are being written to the wrong location, or your texture is being sampled *from* the wrong location. Either way, there's a clear miscommunication. Assuming that `vs_uv_out` really is non-normalized, then you should either use `texelFetch` or you should normalize it. Fortunately, you're using OpenGL 4.5, so that ought to be fairly simple:

```
ivec2 size = textureSize(tex);
vec2 texCoord = vs_uv_out / size;
out_color = texture(tex, texCoord);
```

Comment: i already tried glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS) and it didn't work, so GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT doesn't work too

Comment: @FamZ: No, that was wrong. It just wasn't the *only* thing wrong. See edits.